# How to access and possibly modify an attribute of a child lit-element component?

Tags: javascript, lit-element

From inside a **method** for a **Lit-element** component class definition: how to access an **attribute** of a child component? I'm trying to get/modify the child's attribute value.
e.g.

```
...
render() {
  return html`
    <div>
      <label for="queryLimit">Query Limit</label>
      <input type="number" name="queryLimit" id="queryLimit" value="7" min="1" max="21">
      <button @click="${this.changeQueryLimit}">change attributes</button>
    </div>
    <topics-unicode-tree-core querylimit="9" id="topics-tree"></topics-tree>
  `;
}
...
changeQueryLimit() {
  let topicsTree = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("topics-tree");
  // TODO: console.log(topicsTree.querylimit);
}
```

Comment: I had a syntax error, that made me think I can't access the attributes. Silly me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example of how to access and possibly modify an attribute of a child lit-element component:

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/litelement-example-upebgm)

```
import { LitElement, html } from '@polymer/lit-element'; 

class MenuElement extends LitElement {
    static get properties(){ return {
       qlimit:{type:String}
     }
    }

    constructor() {
    super();
      this.qlimit="9";
    }

  render() {
      return html`
        <div id="div">
          <label for="queryLimit">Query Limit</label>
          <input type="number" name="queryLimit" id="queryLimit" value="7" min="1" max="21">
          <button @click="${this.changeQueryLimit}">change attributes</button>
        </div>
        <topics-unicode-tree-core .querylimit="${this.qlimit}" id="topics-tree"></topics-unicode-tree-core>
      `;
    }

    changeQueryLimit() {
      //let topicsTree = this.$.topicsTree;

         console.log('-->', this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#topics-tree").querylimit );

         this.qlimit="10" 
         setTimeout(()=>{
              console.log('-->', this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#topics-tree").querylimit )},200)

    }
}
customElements.define('menu-element', MenuElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

if `topics-unicode-tree-core` is also a custom element then hopefully it also has a property setter/getter (which is the default for lit-element) for it so a simple

```
let topicsTree = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("topics-tree");
topicsTree.querylimit = 5;
```

will do the trick

if not you can set modify the attribute directly.

```
topicsTree.setAttribute('querylimit', 5);
```